# resource not found on mapping default index.jsp file

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have index.jsp file in the root folder of my webapp. I am making this index.jsp to be the default url of my webapp. Everything seems fine but I keep getting the requested resource is not found.

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String index() {
     return "index";
 }
```

**web.xml file**

```
<servlet>  
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
  <init-param>  
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping>
```

If I run my project on localhost:8080/projectname. I get the requested resource not found error.

Please what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem

I added this to my config file

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>

 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```